# Qt, Error when executing step "Make"

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to get the hang of Qt for my C++ applications. I tried a quick test project, but when I tried to run it I got this error.

[image: screenshot of error]

I found a post on Stack Overflow about this error, but the solutions they gave didn't work for me.

Comment: Please post your code and the error message instead of linking to an image.

Comment: I have no code, I only added one item and tried to run that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

tells you that it splits `C:\Program Files (x86)\Qt\5.0\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe` into several strings. Install your Qt into a folder without spaces in its name.

Comment: Thanks, reinstalled it in my C and it works, silly me